# Attempting to use conio.h's functions (specifically textbackground)

Tags: c, windows

I've been researching the C header file conio.h after running into a problem. I've included the header file into my code (I'm running on Windows and using the GCC compiler), yet it seems as if the header file isn't being included thus resulting in the inability to use its functions. Am I missing a step or doing something wrong? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    textbackground(RED);
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CONSOLE ERROR**

> C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\gui\main.c||In function 'main':|
>   C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\gui\main.c|7|warning: implicit
>   declaration of function 'textbackground'|
>   C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\gui\main.c|7|error: 'RED' undeclared
>   (first use in this function)|
>   C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\gui\main.c|7|error: (Each undeclared
>   identifier is reported only once|
>   C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\gui\main.c|7|error: for each function
>   it appears in.)| ||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings ===|

Comment: Are you getting a compile error?  If so, what is it?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @CareyGregory Woops. Edited OP.

Comment: Check contents of the header. It can be that there is some #ifdef there.

Comment: This dates back to the previous century, textbackground was a Borland specific function.  It's out of business.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, I would recommend you to use

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleTextAttribute(
  _In_  HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  WORD wAttributes
);
```

And other functions from `wincon.h`. I used them a lot. They work fine.

Comment: Not sure if I'm mixing this up with a similar function, but I swore I read somewhere on SO that this was an extremely outdated way to go? But I'm more than likely thinking of something else...

Comment: I am not sure that `wincon.h` is out dated. As long as you are targeting Windows, this is fine.

Comment: Ah, I must have been mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you're sure you don't care about portability I would go with the Win32 functions.

Comment: But any idea as to why the code in the OP wasn't working? Definitely don't want this to go unsolved as I'm sure I did everything correctly (or not as there is an error...).

Comment: No, you probably didn't do everything correctly.  My guess would be the definitions you need are inside an #ifdef because if the compiler wasn't finding the header you'd get obvious errors.  I'd go take a look at conio.h and see what textbackground and RED depend on.

Comment: See Hans Passant's comment.  Are these items even declared at all in conio.h?

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm new to the language, so please bear with me. Wouldn't the header be the default setup/standard for the file? It's not as if I went in and manually modified anything within the header file.

Comment: Yes, the header should be the standard that came with gcc.  I'm not suggesting that you edited it.  But have you looked at it to see if textbackground and RED are even declared there?  It appears they're not.  They're definitely not in Visual Studio's copy of conio.h.

Comment: @X33: to put the question a different way, what made you think that textbackground was a function provided by conio.h?